# "a new English technique" vs. "techniques"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

[From a tutorial](https://youtu.be/A6aE4nceJt8?t=83)

> There are seven possible intonation patterns in English:

1. rising
2. falling
3. rising-falling
4. falling-rising
5. flat
6. high
7. low

When I refer to those patterns, should I consider "technique" an uncountable noun or a countable noun?

```
This is a fresh new English technique to me.

Those are fresh new English techniques to me.
```

Which one is more natural?

Are there any other expression more natural could be used in this particular situation?

Comment: *This is a **whole** new **approach to learning** English **for** me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you're referring to.

If the idea of breaking English speech into intonation patterns is new to you, you could refer to it as "This is a fresh new English technique to me", and technique would refer to the entire construct of breaking things down in this way.

If noticing each intonation pattern is new to you and you want to refer to all of them as ways you are now noticing pronunciation, you could say "These are fresh new techniques to me", referring to all of them as members of a group.

I will also just say that "fresh new" sounds redundant; if it is new, it is fresh, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you. Before the quotation, I didn't even know what "intonation" exactly mean. I just knew that it was about pronunciation. Which one should I go with?

Comment: Based on that comment, I think you're talking about the idea of intonations, and therefore should refer to that idea in the singular.